# How to solve $ (e^{x^4} -1) u' = 0 $ in the distributional sense?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, linear-pde

How to solve $ (e^{x^4} -1) u' = 0 $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ in the distributional sense? Since $ (e^{x^4} -1) = 0 $ for $ x = 0 $, we cannot divide the equation by this expression, so we somehow have to work with it. But how? I would be grateful for any clues!

Comment: How about "dividing by" $\int_0^1\exp (t x^4)\mathrm{d}t$ to arrive at $x^4u'=0$?

Comment: @KBDave Thank you. I can't see how it could work... In order to be bale to multiply a function $f$ with a distribution, we need $f \in C^\infty$, don't we? But $ f(x) = \int_0^1\exp (t x^4)\mathrm{d}t $ is not even continuous (unless I'm making a silly mistake). Indeed, $ f(0) = e $, whereas for $x \neq 0 $ we have  $ \int_0^1\exp (t x^4)\mathrm{d}t = x^{-4} (e^{x^4} -1)$. But I'm quite new to the theory of distributions, so maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: you're making a silly mistake

Comment: I would be grateful if you would explain it to me, even if it is very silly.

Comment: Substitute $x=0$ in the integral. Then its value is $1$. For general $x$, we have that it is the analytic extension of $(\exp x^4 -1)/x^4$ to $x=0$.

Comment: Oh yes, a silly mistake indeed. Thank you! I don't manage to see, though, why we can conclude that the equation reduces to $ ^4′=0 $, whose solution is known. Would we not have to show that $ (e^{x^4} -1) / (\int_0^1\exp (t x^4)\mathrm{d}t) = 1 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $, since $ f u'(\varphi) = u'(f \varphi) = u'(\varphi) $ iff $ f = 1 $? Or have I again overlooked something?

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat sketchy solution:

Around $x=0$ we have $e^{x^4} - 1 = O(x^4)$. This means that we practically have the equation $x^4 u' = 0$ at $x=0$. This has solutions $u' = a\delta + b\delta' + c\delta'' + d\delta'''$ for some constants $a,b,c,d$. But away from $x=0$ we can divide by $e^{x^4} - 1$. The full solution should thus be
$$u' = a\delta + b\delta' + c\delta'' + d\delta''',$$
for some constants $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Since $(e^{x^4}-1)u'=0$ we have $\mbox{supp}(u') \subseteq \{ 0 \}$.

This gives that there exists some $N$ such that 
$$u'=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k D^{K}$$
where $D^k$ is $D^k(f)=f^{(k)}(0)$ (or if you preffer $D^k(f)=(-1)^kf^{(k)}(0)$, the choice is irrelevant since $(-1)^k$ can go into $a_k$).

**Hint 2**
$$0=(e^{x^4}-1)u'=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k (e^{x^4}-1)D^{K}$$
and you can calculate explicitely $(e^{x^4}-1)D^{K}$. You are going to discover that this is $0$ for the first few values of $k$, and non-zero for the rest. From there, the rest is easy.

**Hint 3** Once you get explicitely $u'$, you can calculate $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the definition ($D$ the test function space).
$$\begin{align}
(\mathrm{e}^{x^4}-1)u' &=0 \\
\forall_{\phi:D}\langle u',(\mathrm{e}^{x^4}-1)\phi \rangle &=0 \\
\forall_{\phi:D}\langle u,((\mathrm{e}^{x^4}-1)\phi)' \rangle &=0\text{.} \\
\end{align}$$

Next, divide the equation by $$f(x)=\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{tx^4}\mathrm{d}t\text{.}$$ To "divide" means to substitute $\phi\leftarrow \tfrac{1}{f}\phi$ for the quantified variable $\phi$, which is legitimate because $f$ is an invertible linear map $f\cdot(\quad): D\to D$ and consequently does not change the domain of quantification $D$. Thus

$$\forall_{\phi:D}\langle u,(x^4\phi)' \rangle = 0\text{.}$$

That is, if we define $L:D\to D$ to be $L\phi=(x^4\phi)'$, we are being asked to find a cokernel

$$\mathrm{coker}\,L:D \to \mathrm{cod}\, \mathrm{coker}\,L$$

the vector space of necessary and sufficient conditions on a test function $\psi$ for it to be of the form $\psi = L\phi = (x^4\phi)'$ for some $\phi:D$.

Now, if such a $\phi$ exists, then it must be the case that

$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{-\infty}^x\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x\text{.}$$
However, this $\phi$ *does not belong to $D$* in general. Recall that a function belongs to $D$ iff it is compactly supported and smooth. For $\phi$ to be compactly supported, it is necessary and sufficient for to have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x =0\text{.}$$

As for smoothness: expand

$$\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{-\infty}^x\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{-\infty}^0\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x +\frac{\psi(0)}{x^3}+\frac{\psi^{(1)}(0)}{2x^2}+\frac{\psi^{(2)}(0)}{6x}+\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1 \psi^{(3)}(tx)(1-t)^3 \mathrm{d}t\text{.}$$
Then the necessary and sufficient conditions for $\phi$ to be smooth are
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^0\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x&=0 &
\psi(0) &= 0 &
\psi^{(1)}(0) &= 0 &
\psi^{(2)}(0) &= 0
\end{align}$$
and we conclude that a cokernel of $L$ is given by
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{coker}\,L&:D \to \mathbb{R}^{\oplus 5} &
\mathrm{coker}\,L[\psi]&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x\oplus\int_{-\infty}^0\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x \oplus \psi(0) \oplus \psi'(0)\oplus \psi''(0)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
The span of the linear functionals on the right side of this definition are the solution to the original differential equation.